# Django Celery: Task not updating the database

Tags: python, django, celery

I have django app which uses celery,

```
@task(name="execute_java_task")
def execute_java_task(solution_id, stdin=None, stdout=None):
    logger.info("Task started")
    s = Solution.objects.get(pk=solution)
    s.solved = True
    s.save()
```

This task is called when a user submits a form,

```
@login_required
def submit(request, question_id):
    form = SolutionForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.user_id = request.user
        f.question_id = get_object_or_404(Question, 
                                          pk=question_id)

        # Checks if the user is re-submitting a solved question.
        rows = Solution.objects.filter(user_id=request.user,
                                       question_id=question_id)
        for row in rows:
            if row.solved:
                messages.success(request, "You have already solved this question.")
                return redirect('index')

        latest_id = Solution.objects.latest('id').id
        if f.language == 'cpp':
            execute_cpp_task.delay(latest_id+1)
        else:
            execute_java_task.delay(latest_id+1)


        f.save()
        messages.success(request, "Submitted successfully")
        return redirect('index')
    return render(request, 'main/form.html', {'form': form})
```

But the database is not getting updated.
Here is the celery worker info - [[link]](http://pastebin.com/85MAVkGN)

Comment: Did you install and configure `django-celery`?

Comment: @limelights Yes I did.

Comment: I have added the worker info.

Comment: Okay I think I got it, but still in a doubt, do I need restart the worker info after each code change ?

Comment: Yes you need to restart. But I see your task has s = `Solution.objects.get(pk=solution)` and should be `solution_id`

Comment: django-celery is deprecated, consider not using it: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html